# TypeError : 'NoneType' object not callable when using split in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was playing around with the BeautifulSoup and Requests APIs today. So I thought I would write a simple scraper that would follow links to a depth of 2(if that makes sense). All the links in the webpage that i am scraping are relative. (For eg: `<a href="/free-man-aman-sethi/books/9788184001341.htm" title="A Free Man">`) So to make them absolute I thought I would join the page url with the relative links using `urljoin`.

To do this I had to first extract the href value from the `<a>` tags and for that I thought I would use `split`:

```
#!/bin/python
#crawl.py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin

html_source=requests.get("http://www.flipkart.com/books")
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_source.content)
links=soup.find_all("a")
temp=links[0].split('"')
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    temp=links[0].split('"')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Having dived in before properly going through the documentation, I realize that this is probably not the best way to achieve my objective but why is there a TypeError?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`links[0]` is not a string, it's a `bs4.element.Tag`. When you try to look up `split` in it, it does its magic and tries to find a subelement named `split`, but there is none. You are calling that None.

```
In [10]: l = links[0]

In [11]: type(l)
Out[11]: bs4.element.Tag

In [17]: print l.split
None

In [18]: None()   # :)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Use indexing to look up HTML attributes:

```
In [21]: links[0]['href']
Out[21]: '/?ref=1591d2c3-5613-4592-a245-ca34cbd29008&_pop=brdcrumb'
```

Or `get` if there is a danger of nonexisting attributes:

```
In [24]: links[0].get('href')
Out[24]: '/?ref=1591d2c3-5613-4592-a245-ca34cbd29008&_pop=brdcrumb'


In [26]: print links[0].get('wharrgarbl')
None

In [27]: print links[0]['wharrgarbl']

KeyError: 'wharrgarbl'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `Tag` class uses proxying to access attributes (as Pavel points out - this is used to access child elements where possible), so where it's not found the `None` default is returned.

convoluted example:

```
>>> print soup.find_all('a')[0].bob
None
>>> print soup.find_all('a')[0].foobar
None
>>> print soup.find_all('a')[0].split
None
```

You need to use:

```
soup.find_all('a')[0].get('href')
```

Where:

```
>>> print soup.find_all('a')[0].get
<bound method Tag.get of <a href="test"></a>>
```

Comment: Child elements, not attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same error - so for what it's worth four years later: if you need to split up the soup element you can also use str() on it before you split it. In your case that would be:

```
    temp = str(links).split('"')
```